# How to print HRESULT value to messagebox?

Tags: visual-c++

How to print this `hr` value to a messagebox?

```
HRESULT hr = pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&m_spWebBrowser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly print `HRESULT` value to a message box as it of type `long`. You need to map the `HRESULT` values to dispyable strings and show them.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to analyze HRESULT error codes then you can use ["hresult plus" utility](http://www.brothersoft.com/hresult-plus-download-6591.html).

Comment: He wants to print the value which he already has.  Your link is useless for this.